# iOS NSDictionary error

Tags: iphone, ios, json, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I'm parsing a JSON here and am getting the data correctly. However, when I try to put the info in an NSDictionary and the read it, I get this error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cda3d50'
```

heres the code

```
    if (data != nil) {

    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

    NSDictionary *dic = [[res objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"current_condition"];
    self.location = [[dic objectForKey:@"request"]objectForKey:@"query"];
}
```

Any idea on whats going wrong here? Thanks.

EDIT

this is what i get when i log NSDictionary *res

```
 data =     {
    "current_condition" =         (
                    {
            cloudcover = 100;
            humidity = 86;
            "observation_time" = "11:11 PM";
            precipMM = "2.2";
            pressure = 1019;
            "temp_C" = 1;
            "temp_F" = 34;
            visibility = 8;
            weatherCode = 296;
            weatherDesc =                 (
                                    {
                    value = "Light rain";
                }
            );
            weatherIconUrl =                 (
                                    {
                    value = "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0033_cloudy_with_light_rain_night.png";
                }
            );
            winddir16Point = SSW;
            winddirDegree = 210;
            windspeedKmph = 15;
            windspeedMiles = 9;
        }
    );
    request =         (
                    {
            query = "North Massapequa, United States Of America";
            type = City;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Post a sample of the input JSON please. Do you really have a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries in the data?

Comment: The code is assuming everything is a dictionary or a KVO compliant object, but the JSON parse returns other objects, like arrays for example which is what the error indicates.  Log the class of res and the various objects you are dereferencing.  You'll find an array in there somewhere.

Comment: The problem is that YOU DON'T HAVE AN NSDICTIONARY.  You copied your code from some app that "expects" the outer entity of the JSON to be an "object" (dictionary), but yours is, in fact, an array.  Find a different source to copy from, or spend the 15 minutes it takes to study the [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) and understand it.

Comment: I just made this code myself, and if you look the log is showing its a dictionary

Comment: "current_condition" is an array, clear as day.

Comment: (And "request" is not in "current_condition", but is a separate item in the outer dictionary.)

Comment: @HotLicks i just notices that, sometimes I overlook things

Comment: Note that this whole thing could have been easily debugged by placing a few NSLogs in the code and studying the output.  JSON is quite easy to debug with NSLog.

Comment: why so many down votes? it was a legitimate question.

Comment: You can use valueForKey as well like this since it is an array, `self.location = [[[res valueForKey:@"request"] valueForKey:@"query"] objectAtIndex:0];`

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON object probably contains an array somewhere where you expected a dictionary (you sent `objectForKey:` to an array object).

Try dumping the JSON somewhere and make sure it's in the format you expect.

EDIT: As you can see from the dump, `res[@"request"]` is an array (it has `()`). Thus, you are calling `objectForKey:@"query"` on the `request` array and crashing.

Try `self.location = [[[res objectForKey:@"request"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"query"];` instead.

Comment: I just logged it as an NSDictionary and it showed me all the keys I need, the error is occurring on these lines     NSDictionary *dic = [[res objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"current_condition"];
    self.location = [[dic objectForKey:@"request"]objectForKey:@"query"];

Comment: @ChrisLoonam -- The error message says you have an NSArray.  The fact that your variable is typed as "NSDictionary" can't change that fact.

Comment: To really see a JSON structure, I like to print out your NSData using this : NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]); and then paste that into an editor that formats your JSON so you can see the structure. If it's structured as an Array then JSONObjectWithData will not use a dictionary but an NSArray.

Comment: Or NSLog the resulting NSObjects.  An array prints with `()` brackets, but otherwise the output looks very much like "pretty printed" JSON.

Comment: Yes, alternatively you can view the information you need through the debugger. Regardless, it seems you need to understand the format of JSON and exactly how using the json serialization works.

Answer (score 1):

You're misinterpreting the output of the `NSDictionary` log, helped by what I believe to be a long-standing bug.

The output looks like this:

```
data =     {
    "current_condition" =         (
                    {
            cloudcover = 100;
```

This hides the actual shape of the data. See the long break after the = on the data, current_condition, weatherDesc, etc lines? There should be a line break there, so the output looks like this:

```
data =
{
    "current_condition" = 
    (
        {
            cloudcover = 100;
```

The () indicates an array. (Yes, even though [] is used elsewhere. This output is old and crusty, and I doubt Apple could fix it without breaking code even if they suddenly decided it was important.)

This shows the true shape of the data: `current_condition` is an array. The dictionary is the first (index 0) object in the array, not the array itself.

Across the whole data, this would look like this:

```
data =
{
    "current_condition" = 
    (
        {
            cloudcover = 100;
            humidity = 86;
            "observation_time" = "11:11 PM";
            precipMM = "2.2";
            pressure = 1019;
            "temp_C" = 1;
            "temp_F" = 34;
            visibility = 8;
            weatherCode = 296;
            weatherDesc =
            (
                {
                    value = "Light rain";
                }
            );
            weatherIconUrl =
            (
                {
                    value = "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0033_cloudy_with_light_rain_night.png";
                }
            );
            winddir16Point = SSW;
            winddirDegree = 210;
            windspeedKmph = 15;
            windspeedMiles = 9;
        }
    );
}
```

Adjust your code appropriately for the extra level of indirection and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

`-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector` - you can see here that, obviously, you're trying to call `objectForKey:` on array.

Here:

```
self.location = [[dic objectForKey:@"request"]objectForKey:@"query"];
```

`dic` is an array:

```
data =     {
    "current_condition" =         ( // <--- array
```

probably you wanted to do:

```
self.location = [[res objectForKey:@"request"]objectForKey:@"query"]; // res, not dic
```

but `request` is also an array and you'll still get exactly same error...

Comment: Actually, he doesn't get that far.  "current_condition" is also an array.

Comment: yeah, but its not the problem here cause he is not calling `objectForKey` on it

Comment: @HotLicks actually the problem was i made a mistake in trying to get the request key in current_conditions, so the problem wasnt what you were saying

Comment: He's trying to get "request" out of "current_condition", which would be a trick even absent the array/dictionary problem, given that "request" is not in "current_condition".

Comment: yes, you're right, its just too late for me ;) anyway code line is same as I said ;) also the reason is same, just its not the array I was supposing ;)